# Compare email From Email to Email in Excel File with different casing

Tags: flow

I have a flow which monitors an inbox and when an email is received the senders email address is checked against a spreadsheet containing emails. If the email is found then an autoreply is sent to the sender. The problem is that the casing may be different and then no match is found. For example `John.Smith@gmail.com` will not match `john.smith@gmail.com`

I have tried `toLower(triggerBody()?['from'])` in the `When a new Email arrives` action

and  `toLower(body('LookupEmail')?['Email'])` in the `Get a row` action but now it just fails
in the Condition action with message

`InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions for action 'Match' at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'toLower' expects its parameter to be a string. The provided value is of type 'Null'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#toLower for usage details.'.`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As your error suggests, you're trying to compare a `null` type with a `string` type. Try changing your condition to something like:

> `not(empty(toLower(body('LookupEmail')?['Email'])))` is equal to `true`